# After clicking on CONTINUE on step 3 (SHIPPING METHOD) it loads the BOTTOM of step 4 (PAYMENT INFORMATION) --) cannot see the payment options

Tags: checkout

After customers click on CONTINUE on step 3 (SHIPPING METHOD) it loads the BOTTOM of step 4 (PAYMENT INFORMATION) - you cannot see the payment options at all! You have to scroll up to see them! This is a real problem because many customers are not able to figure out they have to scroll up...How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the root cause for this. But in magento RWD theme they have fixed this issue by `scroll to top by jquery`.

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {

    // Adds class so that the page can be styled to only show the "Checkout Method" step

    if ((this.currentStep == 'login' || this.currentStep == 'billing') && section == 'billing') {

        $j('body').addClass('opc-has-progressed-from-login');

    }


    if (reloadProgressBlock) {

        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);

    }

    this.currentStep = section;

    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);

    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');

    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);


    // Scroll viewport to top of checkout steps for smaller viewports

    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: ' + bp.xsmall + 'px)')) {

        $j('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $j('#checkoutSteps').offset().top}, 800);

    }


    if (!reloadProgressBlock) {

        this.resetPreviousSteps();

    }

}
```

[Check this file](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/opcheckout_rwd.js)

Comment: Thank you Meenakshi - where do I put this code into? Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Create a new js file and add that to checkout/onepage page.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml#L31

Comment: I'm so sorry to be so dumb - I would create a something.js file where I put this code into, right? How do I reference that in the checkout then? thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Check my pervious comment you have to add this js file in template/checkout/onepage.phtml

Comment: are you talking about: /public_html/app/design/frontend/MYtheme/default/template/checkout ? I don't have onepage.phtml in there! I don't think I use ONE PAGE checkout....just the regular one...

Comment: Get a copy of that file from base theme and put in your theme

Comment: I found onepage.phtml in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout Now I'm a bit confused - I don't mind changing it here if needs to be but do I just add the code into this file? (onepage.phtml) because I see these 2 lines in there the same as in your code that you gave me the reference to: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>

Comment: Meenakshi - can I please ask you when you get a chance to make it real simple for me? Like STEP1 - make a file blahblah.js STEP 2: Place it into whateverDIRECTORY STEP 3: add this code to onepage.phtml or something like this - I've been trying to figure this out all day today (pulling my hair out) while it seems like a quick fix ;-(  Thank you SO MUCH! :-*

Comment: Step 1 is correct. Step 2: put that file in `skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/js/blabla.js`. Step 3: add `<script type="text/Javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/blabla.js')"?>"></script>` in onepage.phtm

Comment: I did it and I got the following Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"?>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/MYACCOUNT/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml on line 33

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26068/discussion-between-meenakshi-sundaram-r-and-allysin).

Comment: Can you show your onepage.phtml file

Comment: I am on chat now...

Comment: is the path to the js file correct?

Comment: Where you put your js file???

Comment: /public_html/skin/frontend/accessshop/default/js

Comment: Check the js file is loaded or not in that webpage.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: View page source in browser

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR  Can you update the link to the file?